# PHP: use array_unique on an array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have an array

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [user_id] => 33
        [1] => 3
        [frame_id] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [user_id] => 33
        [1] => 3
        [frame_id] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [user_id] => 33
        [1] => 8
        [frame_id] => 8
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [user_id] => 33
        [1] => 3
        [frame_id] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [user_id] => 33
        [1] => 3
        [frame_id] => 3
    )

)
```

As you can see key 0 is the same as 1, 3 and 4. And key 2 is different from them all.

When running the array_unique function on them, the only left is

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 33
        [user_id] => 33
        [1] => 3
        [frame_id] => 3
    )
)
```

Any ideas why array_unique isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's because `array_unique` compares items using a string comparison. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

> Note:  Two elements are considered
>   equal if and only if (string) $elem1
>   === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.
>   The first element will be used.

The string representation of an array is simply the word `Array`, no matter what its contents are.

You can do what you want to do by using the following:

```
$arr = array(
    array('user_id' => 33, 'frame_id' => 3),
    array('user_id' => 33, 'frame_id' => 3),
    array('user_id' => 33, 'frame_id' => 8)
);

$arr = array_intersect_key($arr, array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr)));

//result:
array
  0 => 
    array
      'user_id' => int 33
      'user' => int 3
  2 => 
    array
      'user_id' => int 33
      'user' => int 8
```

Here's how it works:

1. Each array item is serialized. This
   will be unique based on the array's
   contents.
2. The results of this are run through `array_unique`,
   so only arrays with unique
   signatures are left.
3. `array_intersect_key` will take
   the keys of the unique items from
   the map/unique function (since the source array's keys are preserved) and pull
   them out of your original source
   array.

Comment: Could you quickly elaborate how complex this approach is. For example if the have n items in the array "arr" and each item has m attributes. I just would like to know if it scales for my applicaton, where if have about 10 to 50 items with about 5 to 15 propertys each.

Comment: @ryeguy I think this is going to make all of my hopes and dreams come true!

Comment: @PascalKlein - that's a good question and I'm disappointed it isn't answered. This solution works but serializing every member of the array is going to scale poorly for large arrays / arrays with large sub-arrays. Depending on your specific situation, though, this may be the only viable solution. In my case I was able to simplify by making some assumptions (if $a['id'] === $b['id'] then assume $a === $b) but otherwise mimicking this logic.  That is, I replaced ```'serialize'``` with my own callback that just returns ```$arg['id']```, which is much faster than ```serialize``` would've been.

Comment: Note that sometimes `json_encode` might be faster, so check this too.

Comment: Really like this one, but found out that the removed entries still exist as NULL if you loop over. solved this by putting an array_values() around the code.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an improved version of [@ryeguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561283/52499):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 3),
    array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 4),
    array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 5)
);


# $arr = array_intersect_key($arr, array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr)));
$arr = array_intersect_key($arr, array_unique(array_map(function ($el) {
    return $el['user_id'];
}, $arr)));

//result:
array
  0 => 
    array
      'user_id' => int 33
      'tmp_id' => int 3
```

First, it doesn't do unneeded serialization. Second, sometimes attributes may be different even so id is the same.

The trick here is that `array_unique()` preserves the keys:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(array_unique([1, 2, 2, 3]));'
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(3)
}
```

This let's `array_intersect_key()` leave the desired elements.

I've run into it with [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResults). I was combining results of several requests with different type of objects (think tags). But I got duplicates, since an object may be put into several categories (types). And the method with `serialize` didn't work, since the attrs were different, namely, `photo_reference` and `reference`. Probably these are like temporary ids.

Comment: Didn't think you could improve that but you DID!

Comment: @x-yuri: can you explain why array_intersect_key works this way? intersecting a simple array Array ( [0] => 33 ) in combination with array of array, i.e. $arr = array(
    array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 3),
   ...
);? somehow it will match those 33 even when there is a type mismatch (and other level)

Comment: @Mat90 `var_dump(array_intersect([33], [['user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 3]]));`? It gives me an empty array. But this way, `var_dump(array_intersect(['Array'], [[]]));`, there is a match, because... because it's php :) Well, I didn't mean it seriously. Joking aside, because of the way it [compares the elements](https://www.php.net/array_intersect#refsect1-function.array-intersect-notes). If you give an example where there is a match, I would probably be able to tell the reason. You might want to specify your version. Also, try raising the error reporting level, if not at max. That might help.

Comment: @x-yuri, it is your example in steps: array_map(...) yields (using print_r): Array ( [0] => 33 [1] => 33 [2] => 33 ), array_unique(..): Array ( [0] => 33 ) and print_r($arr): Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 33 [tmp_id] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => 33 [tmp_id] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [user_id] => 33 [tmp_id] => 5 ) ) then the final will be Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 33 [tmp_id] => 3 ) ). What kind of magic is happening here? It is somehow deciding to go a level deeper to compare (I think string compare would go awry as the second starts with Array [vs 33] as first element)?

Comment: @Mat90 I think I now see what confuses you. I've updated the answer, check it out. Do note that the keys of the array returned by `array_unique()` are not `0, 1, 2`. They are `0, 1, 3`. This let's `array_intersect_key()` to return the desired elements.

Answer (score 3):

`array_unique()` only supports multi-dimensional arrays in PHP 5.2.9 and higher.

Instead, you can create a hash of the array and check it for unique-ness.

```
$hashes = array(); 

foreach($array as $val) { 
    $hashes[md5(serialize($val))] = $val; 
} 

array_unique($hashes);
```

Comment: the serialized string should be enough for comparing the strings. when using md5 with long serialized strings, you risk collision. Also, I'd use array_map with un/serialize before and after unique.

Comment: @Gordon collisions are so improbable that it isn't even worth worrying about.

Comment: @ryeguy that depends on your application. and also doesn't change that it's unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: There is no need to call `array_unique` using this concept, as when building `$hashes` this will be already unique, better use `array_values` to get integer based array.

Answer (score 2):

array_unique deosn't work recursive, so it just thinks "this are all `Array`s, let's kill all but one... here we go!"

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Distinct values may be extracted from PHP Array of AssociativeArrays using foreach
- This is a simplistic approach

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- PHP 5.3
- PHP Array of AssociativeArrays (tabluar composite data variable)
- Alternate name for this composite variable is ArrayOfDictionary (AOD)

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** DeveloperMarsher has a PHP tabular composite variable

  - DeveloperMarsher wishes to extract distinct values on a specific name-value pair
  - In the example below, DeveloperMarsher wishes to get rows for each distinct `fname` name-value pair

#### Solution

- example01 ;; DeveloperMarsher starts with a tabluar data variable that looks like this

  ```
  $aodtable = json_decode('[
  {
    "fname": "homer"
    ,"lname": "simpson"
  },
  {
    "fname": "homer"
    ,"lname": "jackson"
  },
  {
    "fname": "homer"
    ,"lname": "johnson"
  },
  {
    "fname": "bart"
    ,"lname": "johnson"
  },
  {
    "fname": "bart"
    ,"lname": "jackson"
  },
  {
    "fname": "bart"
    ,"lname": "simpson"
  },
  {
    "fname": "fred"
    ,"lname": "flintstone"
  }
  ]',true);
  ```
- example01 ;; DeveloperMarsher can extract distinct values with a foreach loop that tracks seen values

  ```
  $sgfield  =   'fname';
  $bgnocase =   true;

  //
  $targfield  =   $sgfield;
  $ddseen     =   Array();
  $vout       =   Array();
  foreach ($aodtable as $datarow) {
  if( (boolean) $bgnocase == true ){ @$datarow[$targfield] = @strtolower($datarow[$targfield]); }
  if( (string) @$ddseen[ $datarow[$targfield] ] == '' ){
    $rowout   = array_intersect_key($datarow, array_flip(array_keys($datarow)));
    $ddseen[ $datarow[$targfield] ] = $datarow[$targfield];
    $vout[] = Array( $rowout );
  }
  }
  //;;

  print var_export( $vout, true );
  ```

#### Output result

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'fname' => 'homer',
      'lname' => 'simpson',
    ),
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'fname' => 'bart',
      'lname' => 'johnson',
    ),
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'fname' => 'fred',
      'lname' => 'flintstone',
    ),
  ),
)
```

#### Pitfalls

- This solution does not aggregate on fields that are not part of the DISTINCT operation
- Arbitrary name-value pairs are returned from arbitrarily chosen distinct rows
- Arbitrary sort order of output
- Arbitrary handling of letter-case (is capital A distinct from lower-case a ?)

#### See also

- php array_intersect_key
- php array_flip

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_unique_recursive($array)
{
    $array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);

    foreach ($array as $key => $elem) {
        if (is_array($elem)) {
            $array[$key] = array_unique_recursive($elem);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Doesn't that do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

```
`

    $arr = array(
        array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 3),
        array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 4),
        array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 3),
        array('user_id' => 33, 'tmp_id' => 4),
    );
    $arr1 = array_unique($arr,SORT_REGULAR);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr1);
    echo "</pre>";
   Array(   
        [0] => Array(
                    [user_id] => 33
                    [tmp_id] => 3
        )
        [1] => Array(
                     [user_id] => 33
                     [tmp_id] => 4
          )
        )
    

`
```

Comment: Please post some explanation along with your code.