# PHP array_unique do not work for my array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

i have a function that return an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => #fff4f4;
        [1] => fff4f4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ffffea;
        [1] => ffffea
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ffc;
        [1] => ffc
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ccc;
        [1] => ccc
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => #eee;
        [1] => eee
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => #fffff0;
        [1] => fffff0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ffd;
        [1] => ffd
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ddd;
        [1] => ddd
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ccc;
        [1] => ccc
 [...]
```

i need to have an array like this but only with unique values.
i have tried with:

```
$result = array_unique($rescss);
```

bur unique entire array in a row, then i have tried

```
$result = array_unique($rescss[]);
```

but doesn't work.

how can i have my new array like that but with uniques values only

thanks in advance

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561248/php-array-unique?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop the array and use a hash array to flag the value already exists, like this:

```
$unique = array ();

$hash = array ();

foreach ( $rescss as $ele )
{
    //seemed $ele [0] could be the primary key
    $eleKey = $ele [0];

    if (isset ( $hash [$eleKey] ))
        continue;

    $unique [] = $ele;

    $hash [$eleKey] = 1;
}
```