# Trouble to understand why I can't have an array of objects with only unique object

Tags: php, arrays, unique-array

I build an array over a loop, so each object in my array are build the same way with the same key and same data type. My array looks like this :

```
$array_of_obj = array(
    0 => {
        date: "2017-11-26"
        hour_array: Array [ "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", … ]
        id_pb: "32"
        id_slot_pb: "704"
    },
    1 => {
        date: "2017-11-26"
        hour_array: Array [ "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", … ]
        id_pb: "32"
        id_slot_pb: "704"
    },
    2 => {
        date: "2017-11-27"
        hour_array: Array [ "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", … ]
        id_pb: "32"
        id_slot_pb: "705"
    },
    3 => {
        date: "2017-11-27"
        hour_array: Array [ "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", … ]
        id_pb: "32"
        id_slot_pb: "705"
    },
    4 => {
        date: "2017-11-28"
        hour_array: Array [ "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", … ]
        id_pb: "32"
        id_slot_pb: "706"
    },
    // etc. 
);
```

So I have an array with multiple identical object, and I'd like to have unique object in my big array.

I find this solution :

[How do I use array_unique on an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561248/how-do-i-use-array-unique-on-an-array-of-arrays)

So it was perfect, even if it was with array of array I think it could work. I test it with the two best anwser I find :

```
$array_of_obj = array_intersect_key($array_of_obj, array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array_of_obj)));
```

AND

```
$array_of_obj = array_intersect_key($array_of_obj, array_unique(array_map(function ($el) {
    return $el['id_slot_pb'];
}, $array_of_obj)));
```

And I have the SAME result for both :

```
$array_of_obj = array(
    0: Object { id_slot_pb: "704", id_pb: "32", date: "2017-11-26", … }
    4: Object { id_slot_pb: "706", id_pb: "32", date: "2017-11-28", … },
    6: Object { id_slot_pb: "707", id_pb: "32", date: "2017-11-29", … },
    8: Object { id_slot_pb: "708", id_pb: "32", date: "2017-11-30", … },
    //etc
);
```

As you can see he skipped the object with key = 2 or 3 (both are the same) and go from 0 to 4...
I made more test building my "array_of_obj" with more duplicate (I had the same structure but with 5 by 5 identicals object and he still skipped the same data.

I tried to check where is my error, so I only do this :

```
$array_of_obj = array_map('serialize', $array_of_obj);
```

It was ok, I had an array of string now with same result (key 0 and 1 the same, 2 and 3 the same, 4 and 5, etc.)

But when I used array_unique I lost the key 2 and 3 as I said :

```
$array_of_obj = array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array_of_obj));
```

I made a little test to check if the data were considered as identical by array_unique even if it's not the case :

```
$array_of_obj = array_map('serialize', $array_of_obj);

$test = array();
    $string_test = "";
    foreach($array_of_obj as $array) {
        if ($string_test !== $array) {
            $string_test = $array;
            $test[] = $array;
        }
}
```

But with this it worked, I had all the unique data serialized in my $test array.

I can't understand why it works for ALL the other object but the same data are just skipped or considered as identical as other even if it's not true...**if someone have some clue or a logical explaination it would be nice, thanks !**

Comment: Can you post your exactly array of objects and not the bad formatted array? I just try in phpfiddle and work perfectly in both cases

Comment: The code is in a PHP script I called in an Ajax function, so I check the data with a "console.log(response)". The "bad formatted array" (the one with the result I think?) is the copy/paste of my console and he is identical as the first I post, without the duplicate and the data with "id_slot_pb : 705" as I said. Could it be a visualisation problem if it works for you?

Comment: Just edited the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I know why I had this problem (but I still don't know why).

The "Mozilla" and "Chrome" console I used to check my data both have different result. With Mozilla I have some data missing when with Chrome everything is okay (I cleared my cache to do the test).

So I think I have my anwser : **it works fine, I have no problem !**

But now other question : **why since Moizilla update their browser I have trouble?**

I will now use Chrome but this bug is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Your `each` **test** on array of string serialized **not work** if the objects of your array are not ordered by `id_slot_pb` or `date` keys. If you paste this code test that i tried on [PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) it work perfectly:

```
<pre>
<?php

$array = [
    (object)[
        'date' => '2017-11-26',
        'hour_array' => ['11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        'id_pb' => '32',
        'id_slot_pb' => '704'
    ],
    (object)[
        'date' => '2017-11-26',
        'hour_array' => ['11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        'id_pb' => '32',
        'id_slot_pb' => '704'
    ],
    (object)[
        'date' => '2017-11-27',
        'hour_array' => ['11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        'id_pb' => '32',
        'id_slot_pb' => '705'
    ],
    (object)[
        'date' => '2017-11-27',
        'hour_array' => ['11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        'id_pb' => '32',
        'id_slot_pb' => '705'
    ],
    (object)[
        'date' => '2017-11-28',
        'hour_array' => ['11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        'id_pb' => '32',
        'id_slot_pb' => '706'
    ],
    (object)[
        'date' => '2017-11-28',
        'hour_array' => ['11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00'],
        'id_pb' => '32',
        'id_slot_pb' => '706'
    ],
];

$array = array_map('serialize', $array);

$yourTest = $myTest = [];
$stringTest = "";
foreach($array as $key => $serialized) {
    if(!in_array($serialized, $myTest)){
        $myTest[$key] = $serialized;    
    }

    if ($stringTest !== $serialized) {
        $stringTest = $serialized;
        $yourTest[] = $serialized;
    }
}

//your test
var_dump($yourTest);

//my test
var_dump($myTest);

//array unique
$array = array_unique($array);
var_dump($array);

?>

</pre>
```

Results:

**Your test** (that not work as i said if not ordered)

```
 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-26";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"704";}"
  [1]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-27";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"705";}"
  [2]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-28";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"706";}"
}
```

**My test**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-26";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"704";}"
  [2]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-27";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"705";}"
  [4]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-28";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"706";}"
}
```

**Array unique**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-26";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"704";}"
  [2]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-27";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"705";}"
  [4]=>
  string(178) "O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:4:"date";s:10:"2017-11-28";s:10:"hour_array";a:3:{i:0;s:8:"11:00:00";i:1;s:8:"12:00:00";i:2;s:8:"13:00:00";}s:5:"id_pb";s:2:"32";s:10:"id_slot_pb";s:3:"706";}"
}
```

Look with your eyes.